# Traveling to France with my maiden name on my passport

Tags: passports, france

I'm planning on traveling to France in a couple of months but my passport is in my maiden name. I never bothered to update it with my husband's last name after getting married 2 years ago.

All of the research I've done (including researching other questions here on StackExchange) indicates that I will be fine traveling if I get my airline ticket in my maiden name. However, the US Passport Service Guide indicates that ***you need to contact the consular section of the country beforehand concerning the issue.***

Does anyone know if France has any more stringent rules that would stop me from traveling with just my passport and airline ticket in my maiden name?

Comment: Yes, your marriage certificate. Preferably the original.  The rest about travelling in France is needless anxiety.  But if the US says to do something I would do it immediately.

Comment: So your passport is in your maiden name, and your ticket is in your maiden name? I don't see a problem. Women are not obliged to change their names to match their husband's. I don't think this will be an unfamiliar concept to a French border officer.

Comment: I have 2 passports a french with my maiden name on it and a south African with my married name on it.
I want to travel to France from South Africa can I USE THE SA PASSPORT TO LEAVE SA AND THE FRENCH TO ENTER FRANCE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry about this. All they care about is your name matching the ticket and passport. They won't ask for your marital status.

Another thing to remember is that there is no Title field on your passport either; no Miss or Mrs or anything like that. Put Ms on your airline ticket if you don't want to be a Miss here.

I got married about a year ago and decided to change my passport straight away, but I know plenty of women who kept their old passport, particularly if there is still a lot of time left on it before it expire. It is absolutely fine to do this; as long as the name on the ticket matches the passport, the airline won't bat an eyelid.

Comment: I know more young women keeping their own (maiden) name than I know young women who are using their husbands names.